# TABS making my laptop too hot even with lowest settings

Tags: hardware, totally-accurate-battle-simulator

I'm running Totally Accurate Battle Simulator game on a laptop with an i5 CPU (8th generation, 8 GB RAM, and GTX 1050 Ti, running Windows 10).
Every time I run this game, the laptop gets too hot and loud, and I can't even play for more than 4 or 5 minutes.

Comment: Have you cleaned your laptop recently? Are you running demanding settings? This game is known for putting quite a stress on hardware when you simulate massive battles.

Comment: i bought my laptop 5 days ago  and i'm running tabs on lowest settings

Comment: If your laptop overheats and turns off, I recommend claiming your warranty. Sadly, there's no warranty for laptops burning one's legs.

Comment: Turning down the settings will not change how hard the laptop works unless there is a framerate lock. Otherwise it'll just keep pumping out the frames as fast as possible, leading to the same workload. Also, can you define too hot? it sounds like its a more powerful laptop and for maximum performance they are usually designed to run as fast as possible, so they get hotter. If there are actual problems like artifacts or shutdowns, you'll need to RMA it

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the temperatures generated by your laptop, you will need a free program for this (unless the manufacturer provides such software with the laptop) - check the temperatures when it is hot.
2. Try to determine if the fans work while playing (laptops usually get louder), you can put your hand to the air outlet to check if the fan is working.
3. Some laptops have software with which you can control the fans (o.n. Asus has ROG Gaming Center) - if you have something similar try setting the maximum power of the fans
4. If your laptop is new and strictly for gaming purposes, I would recommend giving it a warranty, because it shouldn't get hot enough to prevent you from playing games.